# 404 could not find resource lint-gradle-26.1.3.pom

Tags: android, maven, gradle, repository, jcenter

trying to build a signed apk from a opensource android application and got the error for the link https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.3/lint-gradle-26.1.3.pom is not accessible

i try to put this link manually to my browser and after redirecting to https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.3/lint-gradle-26.1.3.pom?referrer link i got 404 could not find resource Error.

is something wrong with the repository? how can i fix this, i can reach the jar file from maven repository but gradle decides to get this from jCenter and hit this error and i can't remove jcenter from repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find out what is wrong but i find a workaround that sort of solve the problem.
I added this line to `dependencies` section of `build.gradle` file:

> compile group: 'com.android.tools.lint', name: 'lint-gradle', version: '26.1.3'

somehow when gradle tries to fetch this jar in build process it fails and not going to fetch from `google()` repo (i have this in my `repos`) but it had no problem getting it when i specify it on `dependencies`. after it downloads i removed it from my `dependencies` and build used it's cached jar file and everything works now.